# Duplicate Dependency Error At Run Time

Tags: android, gradle

I added Parceler Dependency, in build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    // Parceler
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.4'
    apt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.0.4'
}
```

When i build the project, the project builds successfully but at run time it's throwing the below error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/parceler/Parceler$$Parcels$1.class
```

I tried **./gradlew clean** command, i did invalidate and restart cache. I also update my android studio to 12.1 preview and gradle to 2.10, but still the same issue.

Any kind of help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It is because there is a common class in both of your dependencies. You need to handle the duplication.

Comment: that's what the error says, but there are no duplicate libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a duplication of classes between a library (or libraries) and the main project:
http://parceler.org/#avoiding_parcels_indexing

Answer (score 1):

After going through the **parceler.org** doc, i solved this issue by setting **parcelsIndex = false** to each of the model classes.

Parceler will not write a Parceler$$Parcels mapping class if no indexable classes exist and the Parcels utiltiy class will fallback to looking up the generated class by name.